# downloading a web page with powershell using a x.509 certificate

Tags: powershell, ssl, webclient, x509certificate, webrequest

I am having a problem with PowerShell on Windows 10 trying to download a file from a site that uses an X.509 certificate to authenticate the client.  I have this certificate installed in my certificate store in IE and I also have exported the PFX file.  Here's what I have tried:

- [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::ssl3 and also tls12
- trying to get the certificate using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificates2
- trying to set the credentials via Get-Credential and then passing it

I've used the Invoke-WebRequest command as well as System.Net.WebClient trying to get this to work.  The error message I'm getting is as follows:

```
PS P:\PSScripts> P:\PSScripts\DownloadSslHtml.ps1
VERBOSE: GET https://somewebsite.com/GetReports.do?reportTypeId=1234
with 0-byte payload
Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At P:\PSScripts\DownloadSslHtml.ps1:20 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UserAgent ([Microsoft.PowerShell.Command ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke- 
WebRequest], WebException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Now I have seen a lot of people with this "SSL/TLS secure channel" error and they fixed it by specifying the encryption method as TLS12 or SSL3, neither of which is working for me.  I'm confused how to proceed.  Any thoughts?  The website is using TLS1.2 AES with 256 bit encryption ECDH 256 bit exchange.

EDIT:  Here's my powershell code:

```
$url = "https://somewebsite.com/GetReports.do?reportTypeId=1234"
$outputFile = "P:/DownloadedData/file.html"
$PFXPath = "P:/Properties/Config/mycert.pfx"
$PFXPassword = "cert_password"

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::tls12
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cert.Import($PFXPath,$PFXPassword,'DefaultKeySet')
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UserAgent ([Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.PSUserAgent]::InternetExplorer) -Certificate $cert -OutFile $outputFile -Verbose
```

Comment: post your script, at least webrequest part

Comment: @MikeTwc updated with my code.

Comment: Try to use PersistKeySet instead DefaultKeySet. AFAIK specifying tls verision just set minimum verision of Tls you allow it to work with (early versions are insecure). The UserAgent parameter looks weird, why do you use it? For cert auth providing cert parameter should be enough. If you installed the cert you can also use thumbprints vs creating the cert over and over again.

Comment: @MikeTwc Thanks Mike, so I switched my code to use 'PersistKeySet' on the Import call and I took the user agent out of the Invoke-WebRequest.  Still getting the error:  "The request was aborted: Could not create SLL/TLS secure channel."  Any thoughts?

Comment: @MikeTwc I changed it to 'UserKeySet' and it works!

Comment: OK, good. If you imported cert to cert:\CurrentUser\My, try also: iwr $url -certificate "FDA55F8F71ACE8D334875BFBA1B3F7771475CCE3"  (replace thumprint with the one you have)

Answer (score 0):

I changed this line:

```
$cert.Import($PFXPath,$PFXPassword,'DefaultKeySet')
```

to this:

```
$cert.Import($PFXPath,$PFXPassword,'UserKeySet')
```

And now it works!